# Xamarin.Forms Buttons on Image

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Need help, I'm beginner in Xamarin.

[Help with 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9V9c.png)

How I can put 1 and 2 buttons over image?
My XAML:

```
<carousel:CarouselViewControl Orientation="Horizontal" InterPageSpacing="0" Position="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
                                                              ShowIndicators="True"
                                                              Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="250">
                                    <carousel:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding ImSource}" Grid.Row="1" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </carousel:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </carousel:CarouselViewControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :
 you also need to set margins for Im1 & Im2

```
    <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <Image
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.RowSpan="3"
              Source="{Binding ImSource}"
              Aspect="AspectFill"
               />
      <ImageButton
          Grid.Row="0"
          Source="{Binding Im1}"
          HorizontalOptions="End" />

      <ImageButton
          Grid.Row="2"
           Source="{Binding Im2}"
          HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
    </Grid>
```